# How to remove part of a string from a file name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a bit of a workaround to the `<input type="file">`

You can see what I am doing here:

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/zU57Q/

The only problem I am having is that I cannot get rid of the C:\fakepath text that is appearing before any file I select.

How can I stop this from showing

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the best possible answer but simply typing

```
.substring(12)
```

would remove the fakepath

```
$('#uploadme').change(function(){
    $('#filename').val($(this).val().substring(12));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zU57Q/2/

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
$('#filename').val($(this).val().replace(/.*\\/, ''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zU57Q/1/